# How Can I Extract list of prices from website using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Good day -

I am reading the list of cars from Craigslist Miami using VBA. The code is working fine with printing the links for each vehicle, however, I need to extract the price and print it on the adjacent cell. I can get the class name, but I am unable to read the result. Please see code below. It s working fine except for the price:

```
 Sub GetvehPosts()

Dim link As HTMLLinkElement
Dim blog As HTMLLinkElement
Dim price As HTMLLinkElement
Dim IE As Object
Dim html  As HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim URLParameter As String
Dim page As Long, counter As Long
'Dim http As Object
Dim links As Object
Dim blogpost As Object
Dim priceonly As Object
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim increment As Integer
Dim htmlele1 As HTMLLinkElement


 

' This is the first cell that a blog post hyperlink is created in
Set StartCell = Range("A15")

URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' CHnage this to False if you want to hide IE
IE.Visible = True

counter = 0

 'Set the number of pages of the website to go through in the browser
For page = 0 To 480 Step 120  'increment by 120 - total 4 pages
   'Debug.Print page
   
   If page > 1 Then URLParameter = "?s=" & page

  IE.navigate URL & URLParameter
    
     'Wait for the browser to load the page
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    
        DoEvents
        
    Loop

    Set html = IE.document
    Set links = html.getElementsByTagName("h3")

    For Each link In links
                        
        If InStr(LCase(link.outerHTML), "result-heading") Then
    
            Set blogpost = link.getElementsByTagName("a")
            Set priceonly = link.getElementsByClassName("result-price")
            For Each blog In blogpost
                        
                StartCell.Offset(counter, 0).Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=StartCell.Offset(counter, 0), Address:=blog, _
                TextToDisplay:=link.innerText
                            
            Next blog
            
            
            For Each price In priceonly
            If price.className = "result-price" Then
            Debug.Print price.innerText
            End If
            Next price
            
        
        counter = counter + 1
            
        End If
    
    Next link
            
                 
            
            
    


Next page

   IE.Quit
   Set IE = Nothing
    
   End Sub
```

Comment: I am initially trying to print the prices to test if the code generating any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using InternetExplorer is usually a pain. (Selenium works fairly well with excel and has querySelector type functionality)

But sticking with InternetExplorer for now...

Try to work with `IHTMLElementCollection(s)` instead of `IHTMLElement(s)` because the collections still have the `getElement(s)..` methods.

I've never managed to make `getElementsByClassName` work properly. The markup of the data your scraping is likely to be fixed, so working with child indexes is fairly reliable.

I had a go at trying to extract the link text and price for each item on your target and this appears to work for me.

```
Sub getPosts()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As IHTMLDocument
Dim Results As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Result As IHTMLElementCollection

Dim URL As String
Dim URLParameter As String

Dim Index As Integer

URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
URLParameter = ""

Set Browser = New InternetExplorer

Browser.Visible = True

    
Browser.navigate URL & URLParameter
    
Do Until Browser.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
    
Set HTML = Browser.document
    
Set Results = HTML.getElementsByClassName("result-row")
    
For Index = 0 To Results.Length - 1

    Debug.Print "LinkText:" & Results(Index).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
    Debug.Print "Price:" & Results(Index).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
        
Next Index

Browser.Quit

Set Browser = Nothing

End Sub
```

*update*

the above code only looks at the first page, and outputs the link text and price of each post to the debug window. (it was an example of how to access the elements you were looking for)

ive added your page navigation code back in and made it output to the worksheet instead of the debug window.

```
Sub getPosts()
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As IHTMLDocument
Dim Results As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Result As IHTMLElementCollection

Dim URL As String
Dim URLParameter As String

Dim Index As Integer

Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 0
Dim Page As Integer

Dim Link As IHTMLElement
Dim Price As IHTMLElement

Dim StartCell As Range: Set StartCell = Range("Sheet1!A15") ' adjust sheet name

URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
URLParameter = ""

Set Browser = New InternetExplorer

Browser.Visible = True

For Page = 0 To 480 Step 120

    If Page > 1 Then
        URLParameter = "?s=" & Page
    End If

    Browser.navigate URL & URLParameter
    
    Do Until Browser.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set HTML = Browser.document
    
    Set Results = HTML.getElementsByClassName("result-row")
    
    For Index = 0 To Results.Length - 1

        Set Link = Results(Index).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
        
        StartCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Hyperlinks.Add StartCell.Offset(Counter, 0), Link.href, , , Link.innerText
        
        Set Price = Results(Index).getElementsByClassName("result-price")(0)
        
        StartCell.Offset(Counter, 1).Value = Price.innerText
            
        Counter = Counter + 1
        
    Next Index

Next Page

Browser.Quit

Set Browser = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nick - Your code is returning an error. 
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer   "user defined type not defined"
However I used lines of codes for the price from your code, it s printing  the price but the indices are not correct. How can I adjust my code to print the price in the cell adjacent to each link? For example, The below is the current first vehicle and price. My code prints the link, but I need the price like the below:
COLUMN A                                    COLUMN B
2019 CHEVROLET TRAVERSE          $18,500

Comment: I added this reference "Microsoft Internet Controls" and your code is working, however I do not understand the order of the results

Comment: @user3618585 the code I gave was just an example of how to access the elements you were looking for. I've updated the code, it should essentially replace your sub.

Comment: Hello - The URL syntax changes for different cities. Can you please check this link and help me extract the vehicles details and price just like the previous code?

https://wyoming.craigslist.org/search/cta#search=1~list~2~0